# The Click event is not working. I can figure this out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I can't seem to get my click trigger to work.

I've tried the following:

```
//Handle the Main Menu Button Press
$("button").click( function() {
    alert('yep');

});
```

And I never get the alert when I click any button on my site....

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Could you please show HTML for the button as well?

Comment: You'll need to provide some more detail. Is jQuery being loaded? Is that code called within a document ready call or at the end of the page? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: There could be numerous reasons for this, unless you show your html it is difficult to say.

Comment: You know... someytime we all feel stupid... well it's my turn! I was working on my localhost. But me browser was on the www site!!!!! I'm sorry!

Comment: Can we give some kind of award for that? I'd be in the finalists.

Answer (score 1):

might be one of these:
 - you forgot to include jQuery.js script in your header
 - you didn't wait till DOM loaded

try:

```
$( function() {
  $("button").click( function() {
  alert('yep');

 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/63Rkg/)

You need to ensure you have jQuery loaded, you have waited for the DOM to load using

```
$(function() {
   //your code here
});
```

And if you have multiple buttons, you will need to use CSS selectors to differentiate.

I would HIGHLY suggest you read this document, provided by [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

The `HTML` could be

```
<button type="button" name="btnOk" id="btnOk">ok</button>
```

The `jQuery` code could be

```
$("button[type='button']").click(function(){
    alert("yeap");
});
```

or

```
$("button[name='btnOk']").click(function(){
    alert("yeap");
});
```

If `HTML` is

```
<input type="button" name="btnOk" id="btnOk" value="Ok"/>
```

the code could be

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    alert("yeap");
});
```

At first, be sure that :has the jquery code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //jquery code
});
```